# why is my lucky bamboo stalk turning yellow

Tags: lucky-bamboo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why has our lucky bamboo turned yellow?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/why-has-our-lucky-bamboo-turned-yellow)

I have just bought new large lucky bamboo stems, spiralled ones. Two out of 3 are fine, however the third stem began turning yellow very quickly. I have cut off the yellow part hoping this would stop the yellowing but it has continued. The spiral part at the top and the leaves are fine so far. I keep my bamboo in a large vase with water and cleanse it every day with sandalwood incense.

Please let me know what i can do to prevent/stop this happening again.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't clean it with sandalwood.

When you cut lucky bamboo, you need to seal it with wax, if you don't it can get moisture in the bamboo and cause rot.

Lucky bamboo needs fertilizer about once a month. Green Green is great and is cheap and will keep your plant green  http://amzn.com/B004490QYI

Lucky bamboo is sensitive to tap water (chlorine and fluoride). You should boil tap water at least, and possibly use distilled water. Chemicals will make your plant turn yellow and die.

Lucky bamboo is not an aquatic plant, and should be transferred into a soil pot.

Since you have a yellowing stalk, you should separate it from your other stalks to ensure no bacteria spreads.

Be careful when changing water, as really cold water, or hot water can cause distress. You really should only change the water about once a month.

Also, to much, or to little light can cause distress (yellowing) in the plant.

My suggestions:

move it to its own container (isolation)

only use distilled water

fertilize it asap with green green

stop using sandelwood

seal the top if its open with candle wax

think about the light its getting