# Lucky bamboo top of stalk is yellow

Tags: houseplants

[image]

I just got this plant yesterday and I'm wondering if I should cut off that yellow part of the stalk to help it grow. Please let me know and thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, remove the yellow part of the stalk cleanly with a knife at a node where the stem swells. Don't be surprised if it continues to die back.  See this answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/24491/499) for more details on these plants.

If this plant is in water be sure to keep the water topped up and change it regularly so algae don't get started in the medium.